# Ansible error while evaluating conditional: 'action' is undefined

Tags: ansible

This is my first Ansible Role, so appologies for my ignorance...
I wish to start/stop/status the services on my server. I've a role for each task. In my playbook I 've a conditional check to decide which role should be invoked.

```
---
- name: Manage Kore Cluster
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root
  tasks:
    - name: kor_start
      include_role:
        name: kor_start
      when: action == kor_start

    - name: kor_status
      include_role:
        name: kor_status
      when: action == kor_status

    - name: kor_stop
      include_role:
        name: kor_stop
      when: action == kor_stop
```

name/action names match the role names.

```
The conditional check 'action == kor_start' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (action == kor_start): 'action' is undefined
```

Could you advise what do I miss? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The error says `'action' is undefined`. Fix the conditions. For example, default to an empty string. Also, *kor_start, kor_status, and kor_stop* are strings, not variables, I think. In this case, quote them

```yaml
---
- name: Manage Kore Cluster
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root
  tasks:
    - name: kor_start
      include_role:
        name: kor_start
      when: action|d('') == 'kor_start'

    - name: kor_status
      include_role:
        name: kor_status
      when: action|d('') == 'kor_status'

    - name: kor_stop
      include_role:
        name: kor_stop
      when: action|d('') == 'kor_stop'
```

You can test the playbook, for example

```sh
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e action=kor_status
```

You can simplify the playbook

```yaml
---
- name: Manage Kore Cluster
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root
  vars:
    valid_roles: [kor_start, kor_stop, kor_status]
  tasks:
    - name: "{{ action|d('undefined') }}"
      include_role:
        name: "{{ action }}"
      when: action|d('undefined') in valid_roles
```